# Adobe LiveCycle - Drop Down List - Scroll Bar

Tags: adobe

Designing a form using adobe livecycle and have a drop down list with several items in it.

The scroll bar does not appear. Is there a setting or property which enables/disables the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the form using a template. I recreated the template and imported it and the drop down list worked as expected.